# POSTGRES LEAST/GREATEST outer aggregate function not respected?

Tags: postgresql

Here is my query:

```
SELECT 
to_timestamp(floor((extract('epoch' from l.closed_at) / 300 )) * 300) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' as begin_timestamp,
LEAST(((e.details ->> 'bought_asset_amount')::TEXT::DOUBLE PRECISION) / ((e.details ->> 'sold_asset_amount')::TEXT::DOUBLE PRECISION)) as low,
GREATEST(((e.details ->> 'bought_asset_amount')::TEXT::DOUBLE PRECISION) / ((e.details ->> 'sold_asset_amount')::TEXT::DOUBLE PRECISION)) as high
from history_effects as e
JOIN history_operations as o on e.history_operation_id = o.id
JOIN history_transactions as t on o.transaction_id = t.id
JOIN history_ledgers as l on t.ledger_sequence = l.sequence
WHERE e.type = 33 and e.details->>'sold_asset_code' = 'CNY' and e.details ->> 'bought_asset_type' = 'native' 
GROUP BY begin_timestamp
```

and the error it generates:

```
ERROR:  column "e.details" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 4: LEAST(((e.details ->> 'bought_asset_amount')::TEXT::DOUBLE P..
```

I wasn't expecting this error because in line 4 e.details IS inside an aggregate function (LEAST). Why am I getting this error and how do I fix?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you probably confuse `least(variadic` with `min(column` and greatest with max

Comment: Vao Tsun is correct. `least()` is not an aggregate function. You want `min()` instead